# Speeding up web service by writing to redis first, disk after?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-services, redis, jruby

I have a web service that runs multiple DB queries and takes roughly ~500ms-1,000ms (depending on how much I/O EC2 decides to give me at the given junction if invocation). Users want stuff faster than 1,000ms, and understandably so. What I'm thinking of doing is taking the request parameters, stuffing them into a redis queue without writing to disk, and then running a job in an asynchronous queue which does the disk writes. Does something like this happen normally in practice? am I insane for suggesting it?

Comment: If this is essentially just doing asynchronous background processing, you might want to take a look at [Resque](https://github.com/defunkt/resque).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So long as your Redis is persisting to disk on regular intervals, this should work. You want to limit the number of scenarios where you might lose data. A sufficiently aggressive persistence schedule for Redis should work for most cases.

Try to give feedback to the user immediately that their action has been received and is being processed. Nothing is more confusing than a slight delay before it appears that might prompt people to attempt the upload again.